# Are 5.25" diskettes (NOS, unused) as good/reliable as when they were made?

Tags: storage

I have a couple of boxes of 5.25" diskettes (New Old Stock). Are they as reliable as when they were originally released?

When does 'the clock' of reliability start counting? When a diskette leaves the factory, or when data is written to it?

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot factors that determine the durability of anything, including floppy disks.  For a short answer, I'd just say the clock starts counting down from the moment it is manufactured.  As far as how long the disk will last, you have to look at a few different things.

1. The environment the disks are kept in.  They will last longer if kept dry, away from magnets, and in non-extreme temperatures.
2. Number of read and writes.  The more the disk is used, the more it is going to decay, and increase the possibility of breaking.
3. Materials and quality of production.  Some manufacturers made floppies with highly durable materials, and attention to detail on production.  Others, not so much.
4. Using it in more than one device.  This won't break the disk outright, but make it harder to read on some devices.  Operating Systems write to disks differently, and demand specific file systems.  Swapping it between different computers could make it harder to read on others.

I tried to find a standard shelf-life for 5.25" disks, but estimates are as little 3 years, to 25 years.  I've seen some users on other sites state that they could last indefinitely with proper care.

Comment: I am pretty sure normal air would put them around 5-10 years or so. Without heavy use that is, just sitting with or without data. I am pretty sure the air does the most damage here.

Comment: I have floppy disks that are around 35 years old, stored in an old floppy disk bin and they all work fine.  From what I have read, the older disks were manufactured with better materials than the later disks (when floppies were dying off).